# What are armament presets for planes in war-thunder

Tags: war-thunder

In the aviation research tab the overview of every plane shows several characteristics such as max speed etc. Another one is the armament preset. In some cases it is set to 1, others have higher numbers such as 5. What does it do and can I use it to improve my plane and scores?

Answer (score 1):

Aircraft cannons and machine guns able to shoot different types of shells: armor piercing, explosive, incendiary, tracer. Armaments where mostly composed from different types of shells. Pilots changed these composition to better match their needs: more tracers for beginners - no tracers for experienced shooters, armor piercing to destroy engines - incendiary for huge fuel tanks of bombers, etc.

Armament presets in just type of this composition. Generally more presets the plane have the better match for your targets and experience you can find.